# Excel VBA remove unwanted worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have MS Access producing a bunch of workbooks and worksheets. When a workbook is creates there are extra worksheets in the workbook named "Sheet*n*"

I know the following code works but my question is about timing.

```vb
Dim ws as excel.worksheet
For each ws in wbWorking.Worksheets
  oxl.DisplayWarnings=False
    If ws.name like "Sheet*" then ws.delete
  oxl.DisplayWarnings=True
Next ws
```

The above code does not work until I save the Workbook. The issues is that the client is watching for the workbooks to populate the directory and will open them as soon as they show. This causes issues if the above code runs and the client has the workbook open.  I would like to delete worksheets before the workbook is saved.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using a template to create the workbooks? Are you adding a bunch of additional sheets?

Comment: If your working system follows the principles outlined for sharing and collaborating on Excel data as per this article <https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-sharing-and-collaborating-on-Excel-data-3c4fb64f-bf46-42a4-9f6a-73cc6367d378> many issues can be resolved. It is for your kind perusal and not in any way solution of your outlined problem here.

Comment: @skkakkar i get "page" cannot be found error.

Comment: @C.White My "templates" are worksheets in a standard .xlsx workbook. Several different worksheet templates. Each worksheet template could be used more than once in the production workbooks (reports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from when you first create the new workbook, something along these lines should work:

```vb
Public Function BuildWorkbook(wbkToCopy As Excel.Workbook) As Excel.Workbook
  Dim xl As Excel.Application
  Dim dummySheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim sheetToClone As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Set xl = wbkToCopy.Application
  Set BuildWorkbook = xl.Workbooks.Add(1)
  Set dummySheet = BuildWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  For Each sheetToClone In wbkToCopy.Worksheets
    'This is just to handle naming conflicts
    Do Until sheetToClone.Name <> dummySheet.Name
      dummySheet.Name = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss") & CStr(i)
      i = i + 1
      DoEvents
    Loop
    sheetToClone.Copy BuildWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  Next
  If BuildWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
    dummySheet.Delete
  End If
End Function
```

Obviously, you can add the sheets however you need to, but the keys are:

- Specify `=Workbooks.Add(1)` when you create the new workbook, so it is created with only 1 worksheet
- Set a reference to the worksheet that you don't want when you first create the new workbook
- Using that initial reference, delete the worksheet at the very end of the process, before saving the workbook